# Is it possible to allow a content function to run in browser scope?

Tags: firefox-addon

Is it possible (how) by an addon to allow a specific function in a document/page/content scope to run in browser scope?
*(I am well aware of the security implications and this is very specific and for a specific purpose.)*

As a general example, `XMLHttpRequest` in a content script has content scope.
`GM_xmlhttpRequest` via GreaseMonkey has browser scope.

Imagine having `GM_xmlhttpRequest` in a content script and wanting the addon to allow `GM_xmlhttpRequest` to run in browser scope.

Answer (score 1):

There usually are 3 separate security scopes (called [principals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Script_security#Security_principals)) involved when scripting a page.

- the system principal (full access to everything, including operating system APIs)
- the expanded principal of the [sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Components.utils.Sandbox) which may be scoped to one or more origin domains. even when it is only scoped to a single domain it's still considered slightly more privileged than the content itself
- the content principal of the page itself

So if you want to run an addon-script that performs cross-origin XHR *you do not need to grant that privilege to the page content itself*.

You only need to grant it to the sandbox in which the addon-script runs, which is separated by [xray-wrappers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Xray_vision) from the untrusted page-content.

If you're using the addon sdk and the XHR domains are a finite set you can simply [specify them in your addon configuration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts).

If you need to do XHRs to arbitrary domains you will have to drop to a lower level and use [frame scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/The_message_manager#Loading_frame_scripts), which have system principal privileges while also being able to manipulate page content.

For security reasons it might be better to only use the framescript to instantiate a sandbox with a principal scoped to the page and then [inject a privileged XHR function into it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Components.utils.Sandbox#Importing_functions_or_objects_into_the_sandbox), which essentially is [what greasemonkey does](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/5d0d14c6851e9a0e52941291cfaa907c43cfa76c/modules/sandbox.js#L128). Or if your needs for XHR are more limited you might do the processing outside the sandbox and only supply a function that returns the processed result to the sandbox.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. XHR was only an example. I am actually looking for alternative approaches not using sandbox or GreaseMonkey. I was thinking about directly injecting **external scripts** into the page which is fine as far as content principal. However, that would leave the problem of certain functions ie GM_ functions that need to have expanded principal. Is it possible to separate those from the rest of the code, and give them expanded principal?!

Comment: not sure what you mean, you probably should rephrase your question, provide some better examples.